# Download a list of VSCode extensions, for use on an offline system

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a machine without internet access on which I'd like to install a [list of VSCode extensions](https://gist.github.com/max-sixty/a6e11de8576124611433e1808940d90f#file-extensions-json).

Is there an automated way of downloading the extensions while online, so I can copy the files to the offline machine and install them there? Ideally I'd like to be able to re-run the process to download updates.

I'm aware it's possible to [manually download each extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_can-i-download-an-extension-directly-from-the-marketplace), but given the number of extensions and their frequency of updates, I'd ideally like a repeatable process.

Would something like running a script in [Portable Mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable) help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can have vscode installed in the machine which has internet access you can use it to download the extensions and copy it to the other machine.

Let's say `machine A` has internet connection and `machine B` has no internet access.

1. Download the portable version of vscode i.e. `.zip` version from https://code.visualstudio.com/Download
2. After unzipping the VS Code download in `machine A`, create a data folder within VS Code's folder.

The `data` folder can be moved to other VS Code installations.

Copy the complete `vscode` directory to the `machine B` from `machine A`, this  way you will have a portable version of `vscode` there.

Now whenever you need to update the extensions in the `machine B`, you can update the extension in `machine A` and copy the `data` folder or more precisely copy the `extensions` folder in the `machine B`.

Answer (score 2):

FYR. I just copied entensions from below folder to the private network machine and they worked:

C:\Users\{xxx}\.vscode\extensions

Comment: one more folder:
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime\.dotnet